# Judaism's view of pagans/polytheists

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, avodah-zarah, reward-punishment, afterlife, heaven

How does Judaism view pagans or polytheists? Will they be burnt in hell for eternity like what Christianity and Islam say?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I have edited your title to make it clear from the title what your question is about (readers don't know who "me" is). I have also added a tag to help classify the question. If you don't like my changes, or want to make other changes, feel free to [edit] it yourself.

Comment: Hem, [welcome](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887). I've further edited your question to remove the parts where you ask about your own personal status, as Mi Yodeya can't know enough about you to evaluate you as an individual. If you're interested in discussing your personal status, I recommend [consulting a rabbi](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: Quite an interesting question coming from a user named Hem Netjer-Ra. :)